# Open Mobile Menu on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, menu

First of all, I'm pretty much a beginner at this.

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation main-navigation--default">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navigation-bar-toggle">
      <i class="ion-navicon-round"></i>
      <span class="mobile-nav-menu-label">Menu</span>
    </a>
    <div class="navigation-bar-wrapper">
      <div class="primary nav-menu">
        <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="primary nav-menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-107 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-182"><a href="https://example.com">Homepage</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-820"><a href="https://example.com/service1">Service 1</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-823"><a href="https://example.com/service2">Service 2</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-818"><a href="https://example.com/service3">Service 3</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-821"><a href="https://example.com/service4">Service 4</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-822"><a href="https://example.com/service5">Service 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-183"><a href="https://example.com/about">About</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-184"><a href="https://example.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-185"><a href="https://example.com/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>            
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

And here is my css:

```
.main-navigation,
.tertiary-navigation {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50; }

.tertiary-navigation {
  z-index: 1; }

.navigation-bar-toggle {
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.navigation-bar-toggle {
  float: left; }

ul.nav-menu [class^="ion"]:before,
.nav-menu [class^="ion"]:before {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-top: -5px; }

.main-navigation .mega-category-list-wrapper,
.primary-header .nav-menu.primary {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.nav-menu ul,
.nav-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none; }

.navigation-bar-toggle {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 15px; }
  
.navigation-bar-toggle i {
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.navigation-bar-toggle i {
  font-size: 25px; }

.site-header .nav-menu-container,
.site-header .menu {
  display: inline-block; }

.navigation-bar-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 99999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0 0 0 3px;
  background: #fff;
  display: none; }

.site-header .navigation-bar-wrapper {
  z-index: 110; }

.navigation-bar-wrapper.active {
  display: block; }

.navigation-bar-wrapper:before,
.navigation-bar-wrapper:after {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 14px;
  z-index: 10; }

.navigation-bar-wrapper:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) transparent;
  border-width: 0 11px 11px 11px;
  top: -14px;
  left: 13px;
  z-index: 7; }

.nav-menu {
  padding: 2em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9edf2; }

.nav-menu:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0; }

ul.nav-menu li > a,
.nav-menu li > a {
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 125%;
  display: inline-block; }

.nav-menu ul ul {
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-left: 1px solid #e9edf2; }

.nav-menu ul .category-list {
  top: auto;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0; }

.nav-menu.secondary .sub-menu.category-list {
  left: 0; }

.nav-menu ul .category-list select,
.nav-menu ul .category-list .select {
  width: 100%; }

.nav-menu ul ul a {
  font-size: 105%; }

.nav-menu li#categories-mega-menu {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px; }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navigation-bar-wrapper,
  .main-navigation .mega-category-list-wrapper {
    display: block; }
  .primary-header .nav-menu.primary {
    display: table-cell; }
  .navigation-bar-toggle,
  .navigation-bar-wrapper .primary,
  .category-list .postform-wrapper,
  .navigation-bar-wrapper:before,
  .navigation-bar-wrapper:after {
    display: none; }
  .navigation-bar-wrapper {
    position: inherit;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0; }
  .nav-menu,
  ul.nav-menu {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0; }
    .nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:before,
    .nav-menu.secondary li.menu-item-has-children:after, .nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:before,
    .nav-menu.tertiary li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:before,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:before,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary li.menu-item-has-children:after {
      display: none;
      content: ''; }
    .nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    .nav-menu.secondary li.menu-item-has-children:before, .nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    .nav-menu.tertiary li.menu-item-has-children:before,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary li.menu-item-has-children:before,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary li.menu-item-has-children:before {
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: "Ionicons";
      speak: none;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
      text-transform: none;
      text-rendering: auto;
      line-height: 1;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      font-size: 20px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin-right: 5px;
      margin-top: -1px;
      content: "\f3d0"; }
    .nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after, .nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after {
      content: ""; }
    .nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu, .nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu {
      right: auto;
      left: -16px; }
      .nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu:before, .nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu:before,
      ul.nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu:before,
      ul.nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu:before {
        right: auto;
        left: 12px; }
      .nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu:after, .nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu:after,
      ul.nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu:after,
      ul.nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu:after {
        right: auto;
        left: 13px; }
    .nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul, .nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul {
      right: auto;
      left: 195px; }
      .nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul:after, .nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul:before, .nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul:after, .nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul:before,
      ul.nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul:after,
      ul.nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul:before,
      ul.nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul:after,
      ul.nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul:before {
        right: auto;
        left: -10px;
        top: 8px;
        border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
        border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent; }
      .nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul:before, .nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul:before,
      ul.nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul:before,
      ul.nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul:before {
        border-width: 11px 11px 11px 0;
        border-color: transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) transparent transparent;
        top: 7px;
        right: auto;
        left: -14px; }
    .nav-menu li,
    ul.nav-menu li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 25px;
      position: relative; }
      .nav-menu li a,
      ul.nav-menu li a {
        font-size: 100%;
        padding: 18px 0;
        display: inline-block; }
        .nav-menu li a:hover,
        ul.nav-menu li a:hover {
          text-decoration: none; }
      .nav-menu li:hover > ul,
      .nav-menu li:hover > ul > ul,
      ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul,
      ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul > ul {
        display: block;
        z-index: 101; }
        .nav-menu li:hover > ul li,
        .nav-menu li:hover > ul > ul li,
        ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul li,
        ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul > ul li {
          display: block;
          margin-right: 0; }
      .nav-menu li:hover ul ul,
      ul.nav-menu li:hover ul ul {
        top: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        right: 195px;
        left: auto;
        border-radius: 6px; }
        .nav-menu li:hover ul ul:after, .nav-menu li:hover ul ul:before,
        ul.nav-menu li:hover ul ul:after,
        ul.nav-menu li:hover ul ul:before {
          right: -10px;
          top: 6px;
          border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
          border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff; }
        .nav-menu li:hover ul ul:before,
        ul.nav-menu li:hover ul ul:before {
          border-width: 11px 0 11px 11px;
          border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
          top: 5px;
          right: -14px; }
      .nav-menu li#categories-mega-menu,
      ul.nav-menu li#categories-mega-menu {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        position: inherit; }
      .nav-menu li[class^=ion] > a,
      ul.nav-menu li[class^=ion] > a {
        margin-left: -22px;
        padding-left: 22px; }
      .nav-menu li[class^=ion]:before,
      ul.nav-menu li[class^=ion]:before {
        margin-top: -2px; }
      .nav-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
      ul.nav-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: "Ionicons";
        speak: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        text-rendering: auto;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        font-size: 20px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: -1px;
        content: "\f3d0"; }
    .nav-menu .sub-menu,
    .nav-menu .children,
    ul.nav-menu .sub-menu,
    ul.nav-menu .children {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 10px 0;
      top: 95%;
      right: -16px;
      z-index: 99999;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 200px;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0 0 0 3px;
      background: #fff;
      border: 0;
      transition: all 0.1s linear; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu ul,
      .nav-menu .children ul,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu ul,
      ul.nav-menu .children ul {
        left: 0;
        right: auto; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu li:last-child,
      .nav-menu .children li:last-child,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu li:last-child,
      ul.nav-menu .children li:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
      .nav-menu .children li.menu-item-has-children:after,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
      ul.nav-menu .children li.menu-item-has-children:after {
        display: none; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu a,
      .nav-menu .children a,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu a,
      ul.nav-menu .children a {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 6px 22px;
        display: inline-block; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu li[class^=ion],
      .nav-menu .children li[class^=ion],
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu li[class^=ion],
      ul.nav-menu .children li[class^=ion] {
        padding-left: 22px; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu li[class^=ion] > a,
        .nav-menu .children li[class^=ion] > a,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu li[class^=ion] > a,
        ul.nav-menu .children li[class^=ion] > a {
          margin-left: 0;
          padding-left: 0; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu:before, .nav-menu .sub-menu:after,
      .nav-menu .children:before,
      .nav-menu .children:after,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu:before,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu:after,
      ul.nav-menu .children:before,
      ul.nav-menu .children:after {
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
        border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
        content: ' ';
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        right: 13px;
        z-index: 10; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu:before,
      .nav-menu .children:before,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu:before,
      ul.nav-menu .children:before {
        border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) transparent;
        border-width: 0 11px 11px 11px;
        top: -14px;
        right: 12px;
        z-index: 7; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list,
      .nav-menu .children.category-list,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list,
      ul.nav-menu .children.category-list {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 500px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        position: absolute;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 2px 1px 0;
        background: #f0f3f6;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 30px 0;
        z-index: 10; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list:before, .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list:after,
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .children:before,
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .postform,
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .select,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list:before,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list:after,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list .children:before,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list .postform,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list .select,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list:before,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list:after,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .children:before,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .postform,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .select,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list:before,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list:after,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .children:before,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .postform,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .select {
          display: none; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list a,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list a,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list a,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list a {
          padding: 12px 0;
          display: block; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .container,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list .container,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .container,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .container {
          position: relative; }
          .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .container:before,
          .nav-menu .children.category-list .container:before,
          ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .container:before,
          ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .container:before {
            width: 0px;
            height: 0px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
            content: ' ';
            position: absolute;
            top: -30px;
            left: 28px;
            z-index: 10; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .category-count,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list .category-count,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .category-count,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .category-count {
          font-size: 11px;
          border-radius: 2px;
          margin-right: 8px;
          padding: 4px;
          display: inline-block;
          min-width: 30px;
          text-align: center; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .mega-category-list-wrapper,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list .mega-category-list-wrapper,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .mega-category-list-wrapper,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .mega-category-list-wrapper {
          max-width: 75%; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list li,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list li,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list li,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list li {
          width: 23%;
          float: left;
          margin-right: 2%; }

  .nav-menu.primary {
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 4em; }
  .nav-menu.primary ul ul {
    text-align: left; }
  .nav-menu .account-avatar > a {
    padding: 8px 0; } }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .main-navigation--transparent {
    display: none; } }

.nav-menu.tertiary li.current-menu-item a:before,
.nav-menu.tertiary li.is-active a:before {
  content: ' ';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); }
```

When I click on the Hamburger Icon or the word "Menu" nothing happens.

How can I open the menu on click? Can it be done with just css or with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any trigger to open the menu in your code?

I use `:target` to toggle menu:

```css
/* Added open */
#menu:not(:target) {
  display: none; !important;
}

#menu:target {
  display: block !important;
}
/* Added close */

.main-navigation,
.tertiary-navigation {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50; }

.tertiary-navigation {
  z-index: 1; }

.navigation-bar-toggle {
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.navigation-bar-toggle {
  float: left; }

ul.nav-menu [class^="ion"]:before,
.nav-menu [class^="ion"]:before {
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 7px;
  margin-top: -5px; }

.main-navigation .mega-category-list-wrapper,
.primary-header .nav-menu.primary {
  display: none;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.nav-menu ul,
.nav-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none; }

.navigation-bar-toggle {
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 15px; }
  
.navigation-bar-toggle i {
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle; }

.navigation-bar-toggle i {
  font-size: 25px; }

.site-header .nav-menu-container,
.site-header .menu {
  display: inline-block; }

.navigation-bar-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 99999;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0 0 0 3px;
  background: #fff;
  display: none; }

.site-header .navigation-bar-wrapper {
  z-index: 110; }

.navigation-bar-wrapper.active {
  display: block; }

.navigation-bar-wrapper:before,
.navigation-bar-wrapper:after {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: 14px;
  z-index: 10; }

.navigation-bar-wrapper:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) transparent;
  border-width: 0 11px 11px 11px;
  top: -14px;
  left: 13px;
  z-index: 7; }

.nav-menu {
  padding: 2em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e9edf2; }

.nav-menu:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0; }

ul.nav-menu li > a,
.nav-menu li > a {
  padding: 6px 0;
  font-size: 125%;
  display: inline-block; }

.nav-menu ul ul {
  padding-left: 1em;
  border-left: 1px solid #e9edf2; }

.nav-menu ul .category-list {
  top: auto;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0; }

.nav-menu.secondary .sub-menu.category-list {
  left: 0; }

.nav-menu ul .category-list select,
.nav-menu ul .category-list .select {
  width: 100%; }

.nav-menu ul ul a {
  font-size: 105%; }

.nav-menu li#categories-mega-menu {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px; }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navigation-bar-wrapper,
  .main-navigation .mega-category-list-wrapper {
    display: block; }
  .primary-header .nav-menu.primary {
    display: table-cell; }
  .navigation-bar-toggle,
  .navigation-bar-wrapper .primary,
  .category-list .postform-wrapper,
  .navigation-bar-wrapper:before,
  .navigation-bar-wrapper:after {
    display: none; }
  .navigation-bar-wrapper {
    position: inherit;
    top: auto;
    left: auto;
    right: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 0; }
  .nav-menu,
  ul.nav-menu {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0; }
    .nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:before,
    .nav-menu.secondary li.menu-item-has-children:after, .nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:before,
    .nav-menu.tertiary li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:before,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:before,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary li.menu-item-has-children:after {
      display: none;
      content: ''; }
    .nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    .nav-menu.secondary li.menu-item-has-children:before, .nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    .nav-menu.tertiary li.menu-item-has-children:before,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary li.menu-item-has-children:before,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary li.menu-item-has-children:before {
      display: inline-block;
      font-family: "Ionicons";
      speak: none;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
      text-transform: none;
      text-rendering: auto;
      line-height: 1;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      font-size: 20px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      margin-right: 5px;
      margin-top: -1px;
      content: "\f3d0"; }
    .nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after, .nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after {
      content: ""; }
    .nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu, .nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu {
      right: auto;
      left: -16px; }
      .nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu:before, .nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu:before,
      ul.nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu:before,
      ul.nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu:before {
        right: auto;
        left: 12px; }
      .nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu:after, .nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu:after,
      ul.nav-menu.secondary ul.sub-menu:after,
      ul.nav-menu.tertiary ul.sub-menu:after {
        right: auto;
        left: 13px; }
    .nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul, .nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul,
    ul.nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul,
    ul.nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul {
      right: auto;
      left: 195px; }
      .nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul:after, .nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul:before, .nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul:after, .nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul:before,
      ul.nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul:after,
      ul.nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul:before,
      ul.nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul:after,
      ul.nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul:before {
        right: auto;
        left: -10px;
        top: 8px;
        border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
        border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent; }
      .nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul:before, .nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul:before,
      ul.nav-menu.secondary li:hover ul ul:before,
      ul.nav-menu.tertiary li:hover ul ul:before {
        border-width: 11px 11px 11px 0;
        border-color: transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) transparent transparent;
        top: 7px;
        right: auto;
        left: -14px; }
    .nav-menu li,
    ul.nav-menu li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-right: 25px;
      position: relative; }
      .nav-menu li a,
      ul.nav-menu li a {
        font-size: 100%;
        padding: 18px 0;
        display: inline-block; }
        .nav-menu li a:hover,
        ul.nav-menu li a:hover {
          text-decoration: none; }
      .nav-menu li:hover > ul,
      .nav-menu li:hover > ul > ul,
      ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul,
      ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul > ul {
        display: block;
        z-index: 101; }
        .nav-menu li:hover > ul li,
        .nav-menu li:hover > ul > ul li,
        ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul li,
        ul.nav-menu li:hover > ul > ul li {
          display: block;
          margin-right: 0; }
      .nav-menu li:hover ul ul,
      ul.nav-menu li:hover ul ul {
        top: 0;
        margin-top: 0;
        right: 195px;
        left: auto;
        border-radius: 6px; }
        .nav-menu li:hover ul ul:after, .nav-menu li:hover ul ul:before,
        ul.nav-menu li:hover ul ul:after,
        ul.nav-menu li:hover ul ul:before {
          right: -10px;
          top: 6px;
          border-width: 10px 0 10px 10px;
          border-color: transparent transparent transparent #fff; }
        .nav-menu li:hover ul ul:before,
        ul.nav-menu li:hover ul ul:before {
          border-width: 11px 0 11px 11px;
          border-color: transparent transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
          top: 5px;
          right: -14px; }
      .nav-menu li#categories-mega-menu,
      ul.nav-menu li#categories-mega-menu {
        margin-top: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        position: inherit; }
      .nav-menu li[class^=ion] > a,
      ul.nav-menu li[class^=ion] > a {
        margin-left: -22px;
        padding-left: 22px; }
      .nav-menu li[class^=ion]:before,
      ul.nav-menu li[class^=ion]:before {
        margin-top: -2px; }
      .nav-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
      ul.nav-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after {
        display: inline-block;
        font-family: "Ionicons";
        speak: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        text-rendering: auto;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        font-size: 20px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-left: 5px;
        margin-top: -1px;
        content: "\f3d0"; }
    .nav-menu .sub-menu,
    .nav-menu .children,
    ul.nav-menu .sub-menu,
    ul.nav-menu .children {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      padding: 10px 0;
      top: 95%;
      right: -16px;
      z-index: 99999;
      border-radius: 4px;
      width: 200px;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) 0 0 0 3px;
      background: #fff;
      border: 0;
      transition: all 0.1s linear; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu ul,
      .nav-menu .children ul,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu ul,
      ul.nav-menu .children ul {
        left: 0;
        right: auto; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu li:last-child,
      .nav-menu .children li:last-child,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu li:last-child,
      ul.nav-menu .children li:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
      .nav-menu .children li.menu-item-has-children:after,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu li.menu-item-has-children:after,
      ul.nav-menu .children li.menu-item-has-children:after {
        display: none; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu a,
      .nav-menu .children a,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu a,
      ul.nav-menu .children a {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 6px 22px;
        display: inline-block; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu li[class^=ion],
      .nav-menu .children li[class^=ion],
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu li[class^=ion],
      ul.nav-menu .children li[class^=ion] {
        padding-left: 22px; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu li[class^=ion] > a,
        .nav-menu .children li[class^=ion] > a,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu li[class^=ion] > a,
        ul.nav-menu .children li[class^=ion] > a {
          margin-left: 0;
          padding-left: 0; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu:before, .nav-menu .sub-menu:after,
      .nav-menu .children:before,
      .nav-menu .children:after,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu:before,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu:after,
      ul.nav-menu .children:before,
      ul.nav-menu .children:after {
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
        border-color: transparent transparent #fff transparent;
        content: ' ';
        position: absolute;
        top: -10px;
        right: 13px;
        z-index: 10; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu:before,
      .nav-menu .children:before,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu:before,
      ul.nav-menu .children:before {
        border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) transparent;
        border-width: 0 11px 11px 11px;
        top: -14px;
        right: 12px;
        z-index: 7; }
      .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list,
      .nav-menu .children.category-list,
      ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list,
      ul.nav-menu .children.category-list {
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        max-height: 500px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        position: absolute;
        box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 2px 1px 0;
        background: #f0f3f6;
        border-radius: 0;
        padding: 30px 0;
        z-index: 10; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list:before, .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list:after,
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .children:before,
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .postform,
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .select,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list:before,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list:after,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list .children:before,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list .postform,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list .select,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list:before,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list:after,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .children:before,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .postform,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .select,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list:before,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list:after,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .children:before,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .postform,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .select {
          display: none; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list a,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list a,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list a,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list a {
          padding: 12px 0;
          display: block; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .container,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list .container,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .container,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .container {
          position: relative; }
          .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .container:before,
          .nav-menu .children.category-list .container:before,
          ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .container:before,
          ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .container:before {
            width: 0px;
            height: 0px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 10px 10px 0 10px;
            border-color: #fff transparent transparent transparent;
            content: ' ';
            position: absolute;
            top: -30px;
            left: 28px;
            z-index: 10; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .category-count,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list .category-count,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .category-count,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .category-count {
          font-size: 11px;
          border-radius: 2px;
          margin-right: 8px;
          padding: 4px;
          display: inline-block;
          min-width: 30px;
          text-align: center; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .mega-category-list-wrapper,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list .mega-category-list-wrapper,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list .mega-category-list-wrapper,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list .mega-category-list-wrapper {
          max-width: 75%; }
        .nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list li,
        .nav-menu .children.category-list li,
        ul.nav-menu .sub-menu.category-list li,
        ul.nav-menu .children.category-list li {
          width: 23%;
          float: left;
          margin-right: 2%; }

  .nav-menu.primary {
    text-align: right;
    padding-left: 4em; }
  .nav-menu.primary ul ul {
    text-align: left; }
  .nav-menu .account-avatar > a {
    padding: 8px 0; } }

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .main-navigation--transparent {
    display: none; } }

.nav-menu.tertiary li.current-menu-item a:before,
.nav-menu.tertiary li.is-active a:before {
  content: ' ';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
  border-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%); }
```

```html
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation main-navigation--default">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#menu" class="navigation-bar-toggle"> <!-- Added href -->
      <i class="ion-navicon-round"></i>
      <span class="mobile-nav-menu-label">Menu</span>
    </a>
    <div id="menu" class="navigation-bar-wrapper"><a href="#">Close</a> <!-- Added a -->
      <div class="primary nav-menu">
        <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="primary nav-menu">
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-107 current_page_item menu-item-has-children menu-item-182"><a href="https://example.com">Homepage</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-820"><a href="https://example.com/service1">Service 1</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-823"><a href="https://example.com/service2">Service 2</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-818"><a href="https://example.com/service3">Service 3</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-821"><a href="https://example.com/service4">Service 4</a></li>
              <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-822"><a href="https://example.com/service5">Service 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-183"><a href="https://example.com/about">About</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-184"><a href="https://example.com/contact">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-185"><a href="https://example.com/privacy">Privacy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>            
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please rename your class as it is too long to read. And the second is I can't view your HTML document so I will show you my code. And third, from my experience, You need JavaScript to toggle a menu. See down below.

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title img src="Capture.PNG" />SoloSoft: Your Bank of Games.</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>
</h1>

<body>
    <!-- Navbar Section -->

    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar__container">
            <a href="#home" id="navbar__logo">SoloSoft</a>
            <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
                <span class="bar"></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="navbar__menu">
                <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="home-page">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="about.html" class="navbar__links" id="about-page">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="navbar__item">
                    <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="services-page">Services</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="navbar__btn">
            <a href="#sign-up" class="button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

**My CSS**

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.navbar {
    background: #131313;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 50px;
}

#navbar__logo {
    background-color: #ff8177;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #6dd5ed, #2193b0);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2.6rem;
}

.navbar__menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
}

.navbar__item {
    height: 80px;
}

.navbar__links {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 125px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    width: 100%;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #2980B9;
    /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #118fa5, #88ccd8, #2980B9);
    /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #118fa5, #88ccd8, #2980B9);
    /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar__links:hover {
    color: #4eafe7;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#signup:hover {
    color: #4eafe7;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    .navbar__container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        height: 80px;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 1300px;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .navbar__menu {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        margin: 0;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -1000px;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        z-index: -1;
    }
    .navbar__menu.active {
        background: #131313;
        top: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        z-index: 99;
        height: 60vh;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
    }
    #navbar__logo {
        padding-left: 25px;
    }
    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }
    .navbar__item {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .navbar__links {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2rem;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }
    .navbar__btn {
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
    }
    .button {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 80%;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #mobile-menu {
        position: absolute;
        top: 20%;
        right: 5%;
        transform: translate(5%, 20%);
    }
    .navbar__toggle .bar {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
        transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }
    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
        transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
}
```

and lastly my **JavaScript**

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
const menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');
const navLogo = document.querySelector('#navbar__logo');

// Display Mobile Menu
const mobileMenu = () => {
    menu.classList.toggle('is-active');
    menuLinks.classList.toggle('active');
};

menu.addEventListener('click', mobileMenu);
```

Comment: Please don't openly ask for upvotes in your answers